# PHP array broken? $output=''; $output['id']

Tags: php

The following code works with PHP 7.0.33, but stops to work with PHP 7.1.33:

```
    $output = '';
    foreach ($this->fields as $field) {
        if ($field == 'id') {
            $output['id'] = $event->get('id');
        } elseif (in_array($field,$this->properties)) {
            if (isset($properties[$field])) $output[$field] = $properties[$field];
        } elseif ($field == 'allDay') {
            $output[$field] = (bool) $event_arr[$field];
        } else {
            $output[$field] = $event_arr[$field];
        };
    }
```

In PHP 7.0.33 it creates an array with values from a framework, but with PHP 7.1.33 $output just contains some arbitrary value.

**Is this $output=''; an array declaration, because this array-style access $output['id']=... ?**

**Or are there breaking array changes between PHP 7.0 and 7.1?**

Please note: the code excerpt is from an open-source add-on used, I didn't write it, and even more, I can't answer why this design was choosen. All questions regarding this design decision are absolutely right. I just wasn't aware that one could create an array like this. And of course, it makes sense to convert that snippet to more usual array declaration.

Comment: Why do you declare $output with empty string if it should be an array ?

Comment: There's no breaking change about arrays. The only change is that it throws a warning instead of silently changing your string variable to an array. It's forcing you to be more precise.

Comment: Yoi should remove the `;` after `}`.  I recommend not using this script or any add-on from the author -- they seem untrustworthy.

Comment: Please never post an "answer" in your question.  Also, please refrain from making an edit on a closed page unless the edit will make the question qualify for re-opening.  The reason for this is that an edited closed question will be put into the Reopen Review Queue.  Once there, multiple volunteers will need to assess whether this page should be reopened.  However, this duplicate page will not be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a **backward incompatible change** which says that since php7.1

> writing to an out of range offset pads the string with spaces, where non-integer types are converted to integer, and only the first character of the assigned string is used. Formerly (**that is in ph7.0**), empty strings where **silently** treated like an empty array.

More information with example here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.incompatible.php#migration71.incompatible.empty-string-modifcation-by-character.

And you should also answer the question from comments - if you treat `$output` as array, then **why** `$output` is defined as `string`?